# Laravel How to get AI id in controller before saving

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have tried to get the `auto increment ID` from the `booking` table before saving the new data's, but I have errors all the time.

This is the code in the controller:

```php
public function addAppointment(Request $request) {
    $user = auth()->user();

    $booking = new Booking();
    $booking->vac_center_id = $request->get('vaccination_center');
    $booking->vac_id = $request->get('vaccination_id');
    $booking->date_of_shot = $request->get('date_of_shot');
    $booking->time = $request->get('time');
    $booking->shot_number = $request->get('shot_number');
    $booking->isDone = 0;
    $booking->isCancelled = 0;
    $booking->user_id = $user->id;

    $booking->save();

    $booking = new BookingHasVaccinationCenters();
    //here below I want to get the auto increment id
    $booking->booking_id->id;
    $booking->vac_center_id = $request->get('vaccination_center');
    $booking->save();

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

This is the error that I had last time when I try to do this:

> Attempt to read property "id" on null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
    $booking = new BookingHasVaccinationCenters();
    //here below I want to get the auto increment id
    $booking->booking_id->id;
    $booking->vac_center_id = $request->get('vaccination_center');
    $booking->save();
```

use  below code

```
   $bookingHasVaccination = new BookingHasVaccinationCenters();
    //change here 
    $bookingHasVaccination->booking_id = $booking->id;
    $bookingHasVaccination->vac_center_id = $request->get('vaccination_center');
    $bookingHasVaccination->save();
```

Note : always try to define variable with the name same as model class while   crud operations

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you declare with the same name the variable $booking , when you
save the $booking you should declare a instance of object with other name for example

```
$bookingvaccine->booking_id = $booking->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your questions has already been answered, but let me share another way of doing what you are doing, so you prevent this errors and your code is better.

If you have relations between this tables/models (relations functions created) then you can use the relation to create new models between them, without the need of sharing or passing the parent model's ID.

Assuming your User's relation name with `Booking` is `bookings` and for `Booking -> BookingHasVaccinationCenters` relation (strange name) is `bookingHasVaccinationCenters`, you should be able to do this:

```php
public function addAppointment(Request $request)
{
    $booking = $request->user()
        ->booking()
        ->create([
            'vac_center_id' => $request->input('vaccination_center'),
            'vac_id' => $request->input('vaccination_id'),
            'date_of_shot' => $request->input('date_of_shot'),
            'time' => $request->input('time'),
            'shot_number' => $request->input('shot_number'),
            'isDone' => false,
            'isCancelled' => false,
        ]);

    $booking->bookingHasVaccinationCenters()->create([
        'vac_center_id' => $request->input('vaccination_center'),
    ]);
    
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

---

Another super small tip, remember to [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) `isDone` and `isCancelled` to `boolean`, so you can use those fields as `boolean` so you can do `true` or `false` instead of `1` or `0`.

And last tip, try to always stick to the Laravel's conventions: *snake_case column names*, `isDone` and `isCancelled` should be `is_done` and `is_cancelled`.